# remove '.ghtml' from my pages in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom (4.1.1) with this configuration:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './app/App.js';
const Wildcard = () => <Redirect to="/" />;
const Routes = () => (
  <Router> 
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/:section/:news/:title" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/*" render={Wildcard} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
); 

export default Routes;
```

I want that this url, "localhost:3000/section/news/title.ghtml" to match on the second condition, but I'm getting this:

```
Cannot GET /section/news/title.ghtml
```

When I remove the **.ghtml** it works fine.

Is that a way that react router can understand the **.ghtml**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with Vanila Javascript:

```
  const url = location.pathname.replace('.ghtml','');
  history.replaceState(null,null,url);
```

Simples as it is, hope helps someone with this issue